# Float to Fraction conversion : recognizing cyclic decimals

Tags: python, math, fractions

I am currently implementing a `Fraction` `class` for training my OOP skills, and I have got to a problem... In my class, you are able to do `math` operations between:

- Fraction & Fraction
- Integer & Fraction
- Fraction & Integer

And I want to add both:

- Fraction & Float
- Float & Fraction

Since when I work with integers, what I do is to make them a `Fraction` with denominator 1, I want to, when operating with `float`, creating a `Fraction` that represents that given `float`. And that is where I have my problem.

Firstly, the minimum code required to understand my `Fraction` `class`:

```
class Fraction(object):
    def __init__(self,num,den=1,reduce=True):
        # only accept integers or convertable strings
        if not(type(num) == int and type(den) == int):
            if type(num) == str:
                try:
                    num = int(num)
                except ValueError:
                    raise RuntimeError("You can only pass to the numerator and \
denominator integers or integer convertable strings!")
            else:
                raise RuntimeError("You can only pass to the numerator and \
denominator integers or integer convertable strings!")
            if type(den) == str:
                try:
                    den = int(den)
                except ValueError:
                    raise RuntimeError("You can only pass to the numerator and \
denominator integers or integer convertable strings!")
            else:
                raise RuntimeError("You can only pass to the numerator and \
denominator integers or integer convertable strings!")
        # don't accept fractions with denominator 0
        if den == 0:
            raise ZeroDivisionError("The denominator must not be 0")
        # if both num and den are negative, flip both
        if num < 0 and den < 0:
            num = abs(num)
            den = abs(num)
        # if only the den is negative, change the "-" to the numerator
        elif den < 0:
            num *= -1
            den = abs(den)
        self.num = num
        self.den = den
        # the self.auto is a variable that will tell us if we are supposed to
        #automatically reduce the Fraction to its lower terms. when doing some
        #maths, if either one of the fractions has self.auto==False, the result
        #will also have self.auto==False
        self.auto = reduce
        if self.auto:
            self.reduce()

    def float_to_fraction(f):
        '''should not be called by an instance of a Fraction, since it does not\
accept, purposedly, the "self" argument. Instead, call it as\
Fraction.float_to_fraction to create a new Fraction with a given float'''
        # Start by making the number a string
        f = str(f)
        exp = ""
        # If the number has an exponent (is multiplied by 10 to the power of sth
        #store it for later.
        if "e" in f:
            # Get the "e+N" or "e-N"
            exp = f[f.index("e"):]
            # Slice the exponent from the string
            f = f[:f.index("e")]
        # Start the numerator and the denominator
        num = "0"
        den = "1"
        # Variable to check if we passed a ".", marking the decimal part of a
        #number
        decimal = False
        for char in f:
            if char != ".":
                # Add the current char to the numerator
                num += char
                if decimal:
                    # If we are to the right of the ".", also add a 0 to the
                    #denominator to keep proportion
                    den += "0"
                # Slice parsed character
                f = f[1:]
            if char == ".":
                # Tell the function we are now going to the decimal part of the
                #float.
                decimal = True
                # Slice the "."
                f = f[1:]
        # Parse the exponent, if there is one
        if exp != "":
            # If it is a negative exponent, we should make the denominator bigger
            if exp[1] == "-":
                # Add as many 0s to the den as the absolute value of what is to
                #the right of the "-" sign. e.g.: if exp = "e-12", add 12 zeros
                den += "0"*int(exp[2:])
            # Same stuff as above, but in the numerator
            if exp[1] == "+":
                num += "0"*int(exp[2:])
        # Last, return the Fraction object with the parsed num and den!
        return Fraction(int(num),int(den))
```

My `float_to_fraction()` function converts, 100% accurately, a given `float` to a `Fraction`. But as I remember from my math classes a cyclic decimal with a n-digit long cycle, like `0.123123123123`... or `0.(123)` can be written in the form of a fraction with `numerator = cycle` and `denominator = (as many 9s as the length of the cycle)`:

`123/999 = 0.(123)`
`3/9 (=1/3) = 0.(3); 142857/999999 (=1/7) = 0.(142857)` etc, etc...

But with this implementation, if I pass to the `float_to_fraction()` an argument like 1/3, it will parse "0.3333333333333333" which is finite, returning this Fraction: `3333333333333333/10000000000000000`. It IS accurate, since I passed to the function a finite number! How can I implement, in this function, a way of recognizing cyclic decimals, so I can return, instead of a `Fraction` with a `denominator = 10^n`, a denominator with loads of 9s.

Comment: You might want to look at this: [find rational approximation to given real number](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/numth/frap.c).  Although the code is C, it should help you get started.

Comment: Take a look at [`fractions.Fraction.limit_denominator`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction.limit_denominator) and its [source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/fractions.py#l206). It's not a simple job.

Comment: Your `float_to_fraction()` function does *not* convert 100% accurately.  Floats have a binary exponent, but you’re relying on the base-10 representation.  The correct way to convert a float to an accurate fraction is to examine its binary representation; you'll see that you need to divide (or multiply) the mantissa by `2**exponent`.

Comment: This is not going to work out. Don't put the number in a binary float in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to convert a decimal expression into an approximating rational is via the continued fraction expansion.

For x=0.123123123123 this results in

```
r=x, 
a[0]=floor(r)=0, r=r-a[0], r=1/r=8.121951219520,
a[1]=floor(r)=8, r=r-a[1], r=1/r=8.199999999453,
a[2]=floor(r)=8, r=r-a[2], r=1/r=5.000000013653,
a[3]=floor(r)=5, r=r-a[3], r=1/r=73243975.48780,
```

And at this point `r-a[3]<1e-5` the iteration stops. The rational approximation found is

```
x=1/(8+1/(8+1/5))=1/(8+5/41)=41/333 (=123/999)
```

The intermediate convergents are

```
1/8=0.125,      x- 1/8   = -0.001876876877,
1/(8+1/8)=8/65, x- 8/65  =  0.0000462000460,
41/333,         x-41/333 = -1.231231231231e-13.
```